# Delete object using v3 ASK PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having trouble logging in:

```
require 'aws-autoloader.php';

$client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => REGION,
    'endpoint'    => HOST,
        'credentials' => [
        'key'      => AWS_KEY,
        'secret'   => AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    ],
]);

$result = $client->deleteObject(array(
'Bucket' => $BucketName,
'Key'    => $FileKey,
));
```

The $client object is never created. If I run it without the credentials it creates the $client. The Amazon docs say this is how to hardcode credentials. The docs have varying examples from previous sdk's which is really confusing. What's the correct way for deleting an object from V3? I'm not using composer if that matters.

**UPDATE**

The code works but the endpoint value is causing issues. if I use http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/ as the host it tries to fetch http://bucket.bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/key and throws a 404 not found, if i change it to http://s3.amazonaws.com it doesn't work at all, if I remove the host it tries fetching http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/key which gives a 204 status message and the deletemarker is still false and the file isn't deleted. I dunno how to make deleteObject create the correct effectiveuri in the result. I dunno what the 204 status means.

**SOLUTION**

The code works fine without the endpoint field. I hadn't put DELETE as allowed in the S3 CORRS. It works now.

```
require 'aws-autoloader.php';

$client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => REGION,
        'credentials' => [
        'key'      => AWS_KEY,
        'secret'   => AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    ],
]);

$result = $client->deleteObject(array(
'Bucket' => $BucketName,
'Key'    => $FileKey,
));
```

Comment: Any errors while failing to create object? Try to wrap it under try catch and see what do you get

Comment: Oh yeah I had to remove the endpoint field which makes the script work but it doesn't perform the delete as its messing up the effectiveuri by putting the bucket name like http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/file while the actual endpoint should be http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com, I'm getting 204 error. I dunno how to change the effectiveuri. It's trying to delete the wrong url.

Comment: The code works fine without the endpoint. The issue was corrs didn't have DELETE enabled so the file wasn't deleting.

Comment: There is something wrong with your solution. CORS is not involved in AWS authenticated requests. CORS is a solution for cross domain access. Adding DELETE in CORS to make an S3 API work means that something else is wrong.

Comment: It's working. The CORS was probably because i'm testing on localhost and fetching the files using signed urls. I added DELETE permission to CORS and it worked.